# Can we do performed both feature selection and PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, feature-selection

Is there any problem on performing both the feature selection and PCA

Answer (score 0):

After performing PCA you get a set of eigenvalues and a set of eigenvectors. When you sort your eigenvectors by eigenvalue from largest to smallest, you sort them virtually by importance. Now get the first `n` of those and dump the rest.

Thus PCA is a feature selection algorithm.